Ubuntu 24.04 and MSI Katana 15 (B13VGK-1095UK), networking wifi ax211 and random freezes
I recently bought a new MSI Katana 15 (B13VGK-1095UK).
Last night I install Ubuntu. The WIFI worked during installation and did not show up after booting up the first time. Apart from being an extremely frustrating experience, I managed to install some drivers with an external network card.
I then noticed that the system froze at random intervals without being able to recover it. I had to push the turn off button for 10 seconds to kill the system and restart.
Found online that sometimes Nvidia drivers might cause issues so I installed other drivers and now I haven't faced any other freezes BUT...network manager randomly dies and cannot be restarted.
When I try to run anything with sudo at that point the command just hangs and I cannot do anything apart from restarting the system if I want the internet back.
This is extremely frustrating. I've been using Ubuntu for 20 years and every time I have a new laptop what I get is a troubleshooting fair.
Can anyone help understanding why the random freezes of Network manager?
Note.
I've tried running:
sudo lshw -C network
And the command hangs on "Network Interfaces". It's already been 5 minutes :D
